# Database value is ["", "5", "1", "2", "8", "6", "9"] in Rails Console is showing as "[\"\", \"5\", \"1\", \"2\", \"8\", \"6\", \"9\"]"?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Database value is

```
["", "5", "1", "2", "8", "6", "9"]
```

But in Rails console it showing as:

```
"[\"\", \"5\", \"1\", \"2\", \"8\", \"6\", \"9\"]"
```

Any solution to show it as same as the array?

Comment: Mysql doesn't have array columns, last time I checked. So your database values is not an array, it's a string.

Comment: `serialize :column, Array`.

Comment: Where does the value come from (is it a model attribute or do you fetch it via a raw SQL query?) and how did you store it in the database?

Comment: Its a model attribute and I stored my manipulating the values with callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you column is saved as json

```
[15] pry(main)> JSON.parse("[\"\", \"5\", \"1\", \"2\", \"8\", \"6\", \"9\"]")
=> ["", "5", "1", "2", "8", "6", "9"]
```

you can use `serialize :name_of_that_column, Array` so it get parsed when called from db

you can  check http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html f